# Remove Domain URL from downloaded wbsite by HTTrack

Tags: html, css, url, directory, httrack

I have downloaded full website by HTTrack. But after downloading the site all URL contain the Domain name url of the site like: www.example.com/index.html instead of index.html is there any way to remove this url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If structure is not complicated you can use search/replace in directories option, I don't know what editor/IDE do you using but all have that option
2. Also you can specify format of downloaded links even if you are using command line httrack or graphical interface.

This is part of their documentation:
Build options:
  KN keep original links (e.g. http://www.adr/link) (K0 *relative link, K absolute links, K3 absolute URI links) (--keep-links[=N])

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, do you know any other software which download whole website without changing any file directory.

Comment: I'm using **wget** command on linux, but if you are not using command line httrack is the best tool I know for it, just explore and change options before start downloading, don't just use "next" button.